# Not able to resolve issue with api of OpenWeatherApi for fetching weather data of a city using City id using axios in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am developing a small weather app in ReactJs. I intend to collect data using City id from [this api](https://openweathermap.org/current#cityid)

My workflow is this

This is my app.js

```
import React from "react";

import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Dropdown from "./Components/Dropdown/Dropdown";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Dropdown />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here I am calling Dropdown component which contains a dropdown menu, which contains city name and city id. Here user can select a particular city

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Cities from "../Cities/Cities";


class Dropdown extends Component {
  state = {
    value:'',
    lists: [
     {
        "id": 5816861,
        "name": "Afton",
        "state": "WY",
        "country": "US",
        "coord": {
            "lon": -110.93187,
            "lat": 42.72493
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5816882,
        "name": "Air Base Acres",
        "state": "WY",
        "country": "US",
        "coord": {
            "lon": -106.441139,
            "lat": 42.882191
        }
    },
    ],
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  // handleSubmit = (event) => {
  //   alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
  // };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your Country:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.state.lists.map((list) => (
              <option value={list.id} key={list.id}>
                {list.name} {list.state} {list.country}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <Cities value={this.state.value}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

when a user selects a city, the id of selected city is stored in the value property of the state, then i send this value to Cities Componenet

Cities.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Day3 from "./City/Day3";
import Day1 from "./City/Day1";
import Day2 from "./City/Day2";
import Day4 from "./City/Day4";
import Day5 from "./City/Day5";
import classes from "./Cities.module.css";
// import axios from "axios";
// import Dropdown from "../Dropdown/Dropdown";

class Cities extends Component {
  state = {
    day1: false,
    day2: false,
    day3: false,
    day4: false,
    day5: false,
    name: null,
  };
  // componentDidMount() {
  //   axios
  //     .get(
  //       "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&units=metric&appid=b606f9db39d148829c9500a2651c63dd"
  //     )
  //     .then((response) => {
  //       this.setState({ name: response.data.city.name });
  //     });
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className={classes.cityName}>{this.state.name}</div> */}
        <div className={classes.Cities}>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ day1: !this.state.day1 });
            }}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Day1
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ day2: !this.state.day2 });
            }}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Day2
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ day3: !this.state.day3 });
            }}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Day3
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ day4: !this.state.day4 });
            }}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Day4
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ day5: !this.state.day5 });
            }}
            className={classes.button}
          >
            Day5
          </button>
          {this.state.day1 ? <Day1 cityid={this.props.value}/> : null}
          {this.state.day2 ? <Day2 /> : null}
          {this.state.day3 ? <Day3 /> : null}
          {this.state.day4 ? <Day4 /> : null}
          {this.state.day5 ? <Day5 /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cities;
```

Then i store the received value property in cityid and send it to the Day1 component

Day1.js

**This is where the problem arises. I am not able to use that city id in my api url to get the weather data,the portion in the get method of axios which i have commented.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WiDayCloudy } from "weather-icons-react";
import classes from "./City.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

class Day1 extends Component {
  state = {
    DateAndTime: null,
    MaxTemp: null,
    MinTemp: null,
    Humidity: null,
    Precipitation: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
   
    axios
      .get(
        // "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={this.props.cityid}&appid=b606f9db39d148829c9500a2651c63dd"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ DateAndTime: response.data.list[0].dt_txt });
        this.setState({ MaxTemp: response.data.list[0].main.temp_max });
        this.setState({ MinTemp: response.data.list[0].main.temp_min });
        this.setState({ Humidity: response.data.list[0].main.humidity });
        if (response.data.list[0].rain) {
          this.setState({ Precipitation: response.data.list[0].main.temp_max });
        } else {
          this.setState({ Precipitation: "none" });
        }
        //console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (
      this.state.MaxTemp !== null &&
      this.state.MinTemp !== null &&
      this.state.Humidity !== null &&
      this.state.Precipitation !== null &&
      this.state.DateAndTime !== null
    ) {
      return (
        <div className={classes.City}>
          <WiDayCloudy size={100} color="rgb(156, 231, 231)" />
          <h1>Day1 {this.state.DateAndTime}</h1>
          <h4>Maximum temperature={this.state.MaxTemp}</h4>
          <h4>Minimum Temperature={this.state.MinTemp}</h4>
          <h4>Humidity={this.state.Humidity}</h4>
          <h4>Rain={this.state.Precipitation}</h4>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className={classes.City}>
        {/* <WiDayCloudy size={100} color='rgb(156, 231, 231)' /> */}
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
        <h4>Maximum temperature=Loading...</h4>
        <h4>Minimum Temperature=Loading...</h4>
        <h4>Humidity=Loading...</h4>
        <h4>Rain=Loading...</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Day1;
```

Now my problem is in Day1 component: **How to use that cityid property which contains the city id of the selcted city in my api url, in my axios get method, to fetch the data from the api?** I have tried a way, which is in my code of Day1 componenet, by just writing {this.props.cityid} in the api url but it is giving an error that is why i have commented it.

The error which it shows is

```
GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={this.props.cityid}&appid=b606f9db39d148829c9500a2651c63dd 400 (Bad Request)
```

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Updated Dropdown.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Cities from "../Cities/Cities";

class Dropdown extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    lists: [
      {
        id: 5816861,
        name: "Afton",
        state: "WY",
        country: "US",
        coord: {
          lon: -110.93187,
          lat: 42.72493,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 5816882,
        name: "Air Base Acres",
        state: "WY",
        country: "US",
        coord: {
          lon: -106.441139,
          lat: 42.882191,
        },
      },
      {
        id: 5816884,
        name: "Airport Road",
        state: "WY",
        country: "US",
        coord: {
          lon: -107.949257,
          lat: 43.99329,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    // console.log(this.state.value);
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Pick your Country:
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              {this.state.lists.map((list) => (
                <option value={list.id} key={list.id}>
                  {list.name} {list.state} {list.country}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <Cities value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: Accessing `this.props.cityid` should work. What is the issue? you mention an error, what is that?

Comment: @Drew Reese the error is this `xhr.js:177 GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={this.props.cityid}&appid=b606f9db39d148829c9500a2651c63dd 400 (Bad Request)` and this `Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)`

Comment: So this is a server error, which means your code made the request. Please check the network tab in the browser devtools and examine the request that was made, you can validate the `cityid` that was passed. It looks like you either sent an invalid id, though this would probably result in a 404, or something else entirely.

Comment: @DrewReese In the website, an example of API call is given like this `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid={API key}

`  but the URL which I am writing in my Axios get method, is not placing the value of {this.props.cityid} instead it is writing {this.props.cityid} itself as a string and not the value itself. I think this is the error.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are using a string literal to form the quest URL.

```
axios.get(
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={this.props.cityid}&appid=XXXXXXX"
)
```

This results in the a literal GET request for `"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={this.props.cityid}&appid=XXXXXXX"` and results in the 400 error.

## Solution

Don't use a string literal, use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to generate a string with "injected" values, i.e.

```
axios.get(
  `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${this.props.cityid}&appid=XXXXXXX`
)
```

### Update

I just copy/pasted your code into a codesandbox and applied the above fix and I see the city id passed all the way through to the `Day1` component. From here though the issue is with the way you process the response. There is no `response.data.list` property so trying to access further into this undefined property is not going to work.

Please review the [OpenWeather API Response JSON Fields](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON).

Incorrect: Here `response.data.list[0]` is undefined.

```
(response) => {
  this.setState({ DateAndTime: response.data.list[0].dt_txt });
  this.setState({ MaxTemp: response.data.list[0].main.temp_max });
  this.setState({ MinTemp: response.data.list[0].main.temp_min });
  this.setState({ Humidity: response.data.list[0].main.humidity });
  if (response.data.list[0].rain) {
    this.setState({ Precipitation: response.data.list[0].main.temp_max });
  } else {
    this.setState({ Precipitation: "none" });
  }
}
```

Correct: This is the correct field access.

```
(response) => {
  console.log({ response });
  this.setState({ DateAndTime: response.data.dt });
  this.setState({ MaxTemp: response.data.main.temp_max });
  this.setState({ MinTemp: response.data.main.temp_min });
  this.setState({ Humidity: response.data.main.humidity });
  if (response.data.rain) {
    this.setState({ Precipitation: response.data.main.temp_max });
  } else {
    this.setState({ Precipitation: "none" });
  }
}
```

[image: Edit not-able-to-resolve-issue-with-api-of-openweatherapi-for-fetching-weather-data-o]

Comment: It shows a warning on my editor `src\Components\Cities\City\Day1.js
  Line 20:9:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string` and the same error as previous `GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${this.props.cityid}&appid=b606f9db39d148829c9500a2651c63dd 400 (Bad Request)` and this error 'Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62) '

Comment: `src\Components\Cities\City\Day1.js
  Line 20:9:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string`

Comment: @ARPITPRASAD This warning means you are still specifying a string somewhere and trying to pass variables, i.e. `"my string ${value}"`. The warning is thrown when it *looks* like you meant to use a template literal but used a string instead. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string

Comment: After going through the article I realized that the URL which I was writing in the Axios get method I was writing in the double quotation "" which was wrong. Then I changed it to a single quotation but it is still showing the same warning. I think that I am making a mistake in the initialization of the value property in the state of the Dropdown Component in the above code since the id value is an int and I am initializing it with  ' ' . Can you please check. Thank you for your help patience and time

Comment: @ARPITPRASAD Don't use a string literal by using either single or double quote (`'` or `"`), template literals use the backtick (`\``).

Comment: Thank you for the help now my API URL is working, but I am facing another issue, in my Dropdown component in the above code in my state I have the id of two cities when I am selecting the first city its id is not getting stored in the value property and when I am selecting the second city its value is getting is stored but on submitting the value is lost due to which the id of the selected city is not getting propagated to other components (Cities component in this case). Please can you check my Dropdown my component in the above code and guide me where I am making the mistake.

Comment: @ARPITPRASAD Are you referring to what the commented out `handleSubmit` handler is possibly doing? I don't see an issue with the rest of the code in your `Dropdown` component. Can you update that `Dropdown` snippet to the code you're currently using? If I had to guess it's because you aren't calling `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form taking the default form action when submitting, which reloads the page/app (*thus resetting your component state*).

Comment: I have given the updated Dropdown.js in the question. My issue is whenever I am selecting a city from the dropdown menu I intend to propagate the id of the selected city to the Cities.js component by storing in the value property of the state but the id is not getting stored in the value property thus the API URL is not getting the required city id

Comment: @ARPITPRASAD I don't think you're processing the API response correctly. I updated my answer with an explanation and a working codesandbox.

Comment: Yeah the issue which you are pointing to, I have rectified earlier but didn't update the code in the question but the problem persists the value property is not getting propagated. Let it be  I will do some other projects. Once again thank you so much for the help!